# Generate table using all unique combinations from three columns with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have three columns and I would like to interact them to form a new data.table that includes all the possible combinations.

```
col1 = c(1,2,3,4)
col2= c(a,b)
col3 = c(x,y)
```

I would like the resulting table to look like:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
-----------------------
| 1 | a | x |
| 1 | a | y |
| 1 | b | x |
| 1 | b | y |
| 2 | a | x |
....
```

and so on.

I can combine 2 of the columns using the merge command:

```
table1 = data.table(merge(unique(col1),unique(col2)))
```

But it doesnt work for three. Is this possible? Man thanks

Comment: Use the function `expand.grid()`

Comment: `expand.grid(col1, col2, col3)`?

Comment: Or the `data.table` way: `CJ(col1, col2, col3)`

Comment: you guys are epic :), thanks!!